# Chart.js not installing with NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chart.js, npm-install

I am trying to install chart.js . Their documentation for how to install the package with NPM is here : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html

It says to enter the following with NPM to install.

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

However, it doesn't work for me. I get the followin error in my console when I try to install chart.js with NPM.

```
C:\Users\Hashim AHmed\Desktop\Hashim\coding\Project_PlasmaBird\yahoo_finance>npm install chart.js --save
npm ERR! not a package (MY PROJECT DIRECTORY)\yahoo_finance\chart.js
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install (MY PROJECT DIRECTORY)\yahoo_finance\chart.js
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "chart.js" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HASHIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6480-170f285f\unpack-fccf9cad\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HASHIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6480-170f285f\unpack-fccf9cad\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HASHIM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6480-170f285f\unpack-fccf9cad\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     (mydirectory)\npm-debug.logwing error:
```

EDIT: As some have pointed out, the error may lie in my Package.json so here is the code of my package file  (i have censored out some private info) :

```
{
  "name": "projectplasma",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "projectplasma",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.1.2",
    "yahoo-finance": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/(my username)/(my repo).git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "stk"
  ],
  "author": "Hashim",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/(myusername)/(my repo)/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/(my username)/(my repo)#readme"
}
```

Any ideas of what's going wrong here? I am doing exactly as the documentation is saying. If someone could test install this to see if it is working, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me on OS X. Could it be you don't have a `package.json` file in the current directory?

Comment: I had a package.json but remade it since I may have done it incorrectly. Even after redoing the package.json, the error remains when I try to install chart.js with NPM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the `package.json` file in your directory to have this `chart.js` module saved locally.

To create a `package.json` file, use the below command,

`npm init` (which will ask you few questions and will create the file at the end).

Once you create your `package.json` try executing the `npm install chart.js --save` command and see if it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already had a package.json file set up. I deleted the package.json, and all other npm modules that had been installed to my project folder & remade it and reinstalled all NPM dependencies. All of them installed perfectly with NPM except for when it came time for chart.js . It still produces the same error. Thanks for your help noneteless

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `package.json` file contents?

Comment: Sure, I did that.

Comment: Can you try modifying your `"devDependencies": {},` as `"devDependencies": {"chart.js": "^2.6.0"},` and see if it is working?

Comment: Still not working for some reason. It got too frustrated so I just resorted to using the CDN for Chart.js instead. Thanks for all your help so far, but I should be fine using CDN for now. If you still have further advice, I am open though.

Comment: Looks Strange.. I took your `package.json` and added the `devDependencies..` what I had suggested you and it worked fine for me. My Node version is: 7.8.0 and npm version is: 4.2.0

Comment: I made a completely new folder & followed your advice and Chart.js installed with NPM flawlessly. I am not sure what the problem was in the previous folder, must have been some sort of error with the other dependencies I had installed in there. Thank you for helping me resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while **running webpack server** in the backgorund
When I shut down the local server, package got installed no problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue while installing chart.js using npm.

it seems you have to stop **ng serve** and then try **npm install chart.js --save** because I tried the same and it is working fine in the same folder.

Comment: The commands you are executing are the same as in the question stated. So this can not be the solution.