# How to align Chart JS "legend" on right-center

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I am using `Chart JS version 2.x`. I have prepared a bar chart with chart JS. But I like to align the `legend` of the chart in `right center`. Below I am sharing the image.

[image]

And the legend position I want.

[image]

I have tried it from [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#position). In my code

```
options: {
    legend: { 
        position: 'right' 
    }
}
```

**Update 1:** I am using `chart js module in Angular5`

**Update 2:** what I have tried that is https://jsfiddle.net/v4ur38ao/1/

Comment: can you add your fiddle here

Comment: add demo it will be helpful for debug

Comment: @UdhayTitusP , I have updated the question with fiddle. Please check it.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated**

```
options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
              position: "right",
              align: "middle"
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: This is the answer right out of the documentation.  Works great.  The plugins namespace is needed.

Answer (score 2):

use latest version of chart.js : https://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/Chart.min.js for more reference [check this documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/#development-releases) and add `align:'middle'` in your legend it will work's

```
legend: {
    position: "right",
    align: "middle"
},
```

```js
var ctx = $('#myChart');

ctx.height(100);

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
     data: {
        labels: ["APP1", "APP2", "APP3", "APP4", "APP5"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [25, 61, 47, 45, 30],
            label: "Response > 5",
            borderColor: "#5151A1",
            backgroundColor: "#5151A1"
        }, {
            data: [22, 38, 53, 17, 55],
            label: "Response <= 5",
            borderColor: "#408040",
            backgroundColor: "#408040"
        }]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: "right",
            align: "middle"
        },
         scales: {

            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    //max: 100,
                    callback: function(value) {
                        return value + "%"
                    }
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true
                    //labelString: "Percentage"
                }
            }]
        }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

[Check your updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/1jszf9px/4/)

If `npm install chart.js` not working then [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897944/6108882) for more details [check the chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/installation.html).

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine. But in my angular project the `chart js` version is `2.8`, I have added the `align:'middle'` what you have suggested. It doesn't work. One thing is jquery is needed? Thanks for the suggestion and solution +1.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/installation.html. I am using angular 5 already share in question. So I have used this command `npm install chart.js --save`. Isn't it work? Why or How? please update the answer if you can. as I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: try this solution for `npm install chart.js --save` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897944/6108882

Comment: @GuilhermePereira which version of chart js you are using?

Comment: The latest on github

Comment: @GuilhermePereira did you checked this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/1jszf9px/2/. This fiddle has latest version of Chart.js which is 2.8.0, if it's not working can you share your jsfiddle link here

Comment: The documentation says to use 'center', not 'middle' - but that does not work for me either (doco says:Align - Alignment of the legend. Options are: 'start', 'center', 'end'. Defaults to 'center' for unrecognized values.) Neither working for me on chartjs 2.8

Comment: The master on GitHub is still beta version of the lib, the latest stable build is 2.9.4, in version 2 you can't specify alignment so you will have to use the beta or write a custom plugin for it

Comment: @LeeLenalee updated the answer as your suggestion. It's working now.